# c# deserialize xml from different node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows-runtime, deserialization

I've got an xml-file that looks like this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Adresses>
  <Message>
    <Header>
      <MessageID>96</MessageID>
      <Timestamp>22.08.2014 10:25:01</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <Body>
      <Person SurName="Muster" Prename="Max">
        <Adress Street="Street 1"/>
      </Person>
            <Person SurName="Muster" Prename="Max">
        <Adress Street="Street 1"/>
      </Person>
      <Person SurName="Muster" Prename="Max">
        <Adress Street="Street 1"/>
      </Person>
    </Body>
  </Message>
</Adresses>
```

From this xml I only want the part inside the body-tags. I do the deserialization with the XmlSerializer and annotaions. So I have models that look like this

```
[XmlRoot("Body")]
    public class BodyXml
    {
        public BodyXml()
        {}

        [XmlElement("Person")]
        public Person[] Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

Now my question is how can I get the XmlSerializer to serialize from the body-tag and not from the adresses-tag? Do I need another annotation somewhere in my models?

thanks and greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on other constraints, either consider writing a quick and dirty wrapper that would deserialize the whole XML (with `BodyXml` as it's member), or alternatively select only the relevant part of your xml, e.g.:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BodyXml));
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(YOUR_XML_STRING);
using (var xmlReader = xDoc.Descendants("Body").Single().CreateReader())
{
   var result = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

EDIT: without any context I'd go with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

use XmlIgnoreAttribute

You can Add Address property as below

```
[XmlIgnoreAttribute]
public AddressClass Adress{get;set;}
```

Here AddressClass may type of your Address property or some other class.